# Головотяпство

Tags: этимология

Подскажите, пожалуйста, происхождение слова "головотяпство" (разгильдяйство, халтура). Напрашивается аналогия с выражением "оттяпать голову", но при чем тогда значение этого слова?
Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Был в древности народ, головотяпами именуемый... Головотяпами же их прозывались эти люди от того, что имели они привычку тяпать головами обо все, что бы ни встретилось им на пути.

Салтыков-Щедрин "История одного города".

От названия этого, выдуманного писателем народа и произошло слово "головотяпство".

Слово "головотяп" Салтыков-Щедрин нашёл в словаре Даля "Пословицы и поговорки русского народа" в виде **Егорьевцы - коновалы, головотяпы, рудометы. Сами нож точат, а говорят небось**. Что слово головотяп значило в этой пословице сказать трудно, но к головотяпству данное слово имеет только опосредованное отношение. Термин "головотяпство" произошёл именно, от  народа, придуманного писателем.

Answer (score 4):

Слово "головотяп" употреблялось в народной речи и было взято М. Е. Салтыковым-Щедриным из «Пословиц русского народа» В. И. Даля (1862). Широкое распространение получило вследствие применения его великим сатириком в «Истории одного города» (1869 — 1870).

Таким образом, писатель  только сатирически обыграл тему, представив головотяпов как людей, использующих голову подобным образом и не знающих, для чего она предназначена. В связи с этим представляет интерес настоящее происхождение и значение этого слова. В качестве версии можно предположить, что головотяпы - это люди без головы, которую им оттяпали.

Comment: >Егорьевцы - коновалы, головотяпы, рудометы: сам нож точит, а говорит небось.

Судя по контексту, в пословице "головотяп" - это плохой врач, который может и голову случайно оттяпать. Так что современное значение это уже Салтыков-Щедрин.

Comment: Да, я видела эту пословицу. Значит, в ней прямое значение слова. Кстати, последнее слово "небось" иногда пишется раздельно, это "не бойся"?

Comment: Коновалы занимались в том числе кастрацией животных; рудометы кровь пускали; головотяп кому **ножом** головы рубил-резал? Курям да поросям, очевидно.

Comment: Коновал - это и плохой врач, рудомёт для XIX века - знахарь, палачом плохого врача до сих называют, по смыслу больше всего подходит такой ряд.

Comment: В старой пословице "егорьевцы" характеризуются как промышляющие сходными видами некоих *искусств или ремесел*, всегда имеющие при себе острый нож. Что имелись в виду "врачи" или знахари - трудно поверить. Я склоняюсь к тому, что слово головотяп в народной пословице значило - резак скотины.  
> Артем Веселый. Россия, кровью умытая (1924-1932)  
На широкой рогоже завхоз **тяпал коровью тушу**. 

Скотину по головам считали, кстати. "Тридцать голов скота."

Comment: Свидетельство Салтыкова-Щедрина о невыдуманности им *головотяпов* :  
>Наконец, 7) рецензент обвиняет меня в глумлении над народом, и с некоторою даже гадливостью (вот-то опрятный человек!) отзывается о статье: «о корени происхождения», где поименовываются **головотяпы, моржееды и другие племена в этом роде**. Как подлинный историк, Вы, Александр Николаевич, должны быть знакомы с Далем и Сахаровым. Обратитесь к ним и увидите, что это племена мною не выдуманные, но суть названия, присвоенные жителям городов Российской империи. Головотяпы — егорьевцы, гужееды — новгородцы и т. д.